# unas habitaciones rather than without the article

Tags: artículos

I want to ask a question about a preceding article before a noun.

I was reading the following sentence

> La casa no era muy enorme, pero tenía unas habitaciones enormes

which I roughly translated to

> The house wasn't very big, but it had big rooms.

I was confused however, with the use of 'unas'.

Couldn't we say

> La casa no era muy enorme, pero tenía habitaciones enormes

without the definite article, or does the 'unas' signify some kind of relationship between 'casa' and 'habitaciones'?

Answer (score 1):

### Unas habitaciones enormes vs Las habitaciones enormes.

**Some** big rooms vs **The big rooms**

When you use an indefinite article, the noun has no definite quantity.  If you do not use an article at all, then the noun is just that, a lonely noun.

Example:

> Puedo tener unas galletas

This indicates that you only want to have *some* of the cookies, not all of them.

> Puedo tener galletas

This simply indicates that you want cookies, but there is no definite quantity.  It's very generic and to-the-point.

> Puedo tener las galletas

This indicates that you want all of the cookies, even without saying "all of the".  It's equivalent to the phrase "pass the butter".  You want *the* butter, not *some* butter.